# iPhone: Application crashes when I add a layer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

My applications crashes when I try to add a layer in it with `CCSprite`.
Here is some code I use:

```
CCLayer *layerPause = [CCLayer node];  
CCSprite *spriteBackgroundPause = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"BackgroundMenu.jpg"];  
[layerPause addChild:spriteBackgroundPause];  
[self addChild:layerPause z:27];
```

Here is picture also:

[image: picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to retain the `layerPause` variable because it seems an autoreleased object, try in this way :

```
CCLayer *layerPause = [[CCLayer node] retain];  
CCSprite *spriteBackgroundPause = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"BackgroundMenu.jpg"];  
[layerPause addChild:spriteBackgroundPause];  
[self addChild:layerPause z:27];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it simple .. ? Like this:

```
CCLayer * layer = [CCLayer alloc]init];
[self addchild: layer];

CCSPrite * sprite = [CCSPrite spriteWithFile:@"ImageName.png"];
[layer addChild:sprite];
```

Comment: I tried that also but I got the same result : (
Thanks anyway. retaining layer  helped me.: ))